# How to make a fragment be in the exact same way I left it when I return to it from another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, fragmenttransaction

I have a few fragments in my app, but my code opens a new fragment every time I click the button.

I want to know how can I change this, and make the fragment return to the exact same state I left it in.

The code im using right now:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragments);

        MainActivity fragment = new MainActivity();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_place, fragment);
        transaction.commit();

        turnGPSOn();
    }

    public void onSelectFragment(View view) {

        if (view == findViewById(R.id.add)) 
        {
            newFragment = new Add();
        }
        else if (view == findViewById(R.id.map)) 
        {
            newFragment = new MainActivity();
        } 
        else 
        {
            newFragment = new Add();
        }

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to use `SharedPreferences` to save and retrieve information between each Fragments

Comment: How can I save the state of the fragment? and how can I go back to the fragments if it was already opened instead of opening a new one? (`newFragment = new MainActivity();`)? @SiKni8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a new fragment each time because you are calling to `new XXX()` each time.

I think you could use `findFragmentByTag` in order to solve this problem. As you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) the `replace` function can accept a third parameter that is a String, this String can be used as an id to identify different fragments you have used previously.

So to sum up you can:

1. Call `Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FragAdd");` for example in order to retrieve the first fragment.
2. If f is null, that means that you haven't used that fragment yet, so you have to call to `new Add()` if not, use that fragment to replace the old one. For example like this:

> ```
> FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
>             .beginTransaction();
>
> transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, newFragment, "FragAdd"); //or whatever other string you want to use
> transaction.addToBackStack(null);
> transaction.commit();
> ```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: See.. theres a problem: what if I have 6 fragments? Do I have to check them all?

Comment: You can use a String variable to store the tag you want to use, so in your if statement you call to findFragmentByTag and add the tag to that  String. Where do you find difficulties?

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue a time ago, and managed to solve it for applications with one visible fragment at a time; for activities with several visible fragments, you'll need to make some adjustments. This is what I did.-

Create a custom `ParentActivity`, so that all my activities extend it. `ParentActivity` knows  about which is the current Fragment that is showed, and how to show a new one.

```
public String currentFragmentTag;

public ParentFragment getCurrentFragment(int fragmentWrapperResId) { 
    ParentFragment res = null;  

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    res = (ParentFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(fragmentWrapperResId); 

    if (res != null && res.isHidden()) {
        if (currentFragmentTag != null) {
            res = (ParentFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(currentFragmentTag);
        }
    }

    return res;
}

public void openFragment(ParentFragment fragment, int fragmentWrapperResId, int enterAnim, int exitAnim, int popEnterAnim, int popExitAnim, boolean addToBackStack) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    ParentFragment currentFragment = getCurrentFragment(fragmentWrapperResId);
    if (currentFragment != null && currentFragment.getTagName().equals(fragment.getTagName())) {
        return;
    }

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(enterAnim, exitAnim, popEnterAnim, popExitAnim);

    if (currentFragment != null) {
        transaction.hide(currentFragment);
    }

    if (fragment.isAdded()) {
        transaction.show(fragment);
    } else {
        transaction.add(fragmentWrapperResId, fragment, fragment.getTagName()).setBreadCrumbShortTitle(fragment.getTagName());
    }

    if (addToBackStack) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getTagName());
    } else {
        currentFragmentTag = fragment.getTagName();
    }

    transaction.commit();
}
```

Create a `ParentFragment`, to be extended by the rest of `Fragments`, with a tag getter

```
public String getTagName() {
    return getClass().getSimpleName() + System.identityHashCode(this);
}
```

As you can see, the main idea is not replacing visible fragments, but just adding them and show/hide whenever it's needed. This way, the fragments will keep their states, as they're not destroyed until you remove them from the *bakstack*.